# Is there equivalent function to fminbnd for maximum value?

Tags: matlab

I am doing homework in Matlab, calculating numeric integration using different methods like simpson, etc. I need to find value n from formulas for error of method like this one for rectangle method

```
E = (b-a)/24  *  max f''(x)   *   ((b-a)/n)^2
n = sqrt(((b-a)^3  *  max f''(x))   /   24   *   E)
```

problem is finding function for finding maximum value of f''(x) in range a to b.
I have only found fminbnd, which calculates minimum value of function in range. Is there function which would calculate maximum value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the minimum of `-f''(x)` (the negative of the function you want to maximize).